# How to use federated Auth using aws-amplify API without hosted UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

AWS Cognito provides two services: user pools and identity pools. Both are similar but different concepts, ok so far.

I **want** to use the feature federation of a user pool.

I do **NOT** want to use this feature with the hosted UI.

I do **NOT** want to use this feature with identity pool.

I would like to use the federation login of a user pool of facebook or google of a user pool in a reactive native application. For example only with AWS sdk, for example, auth SDK from amplify.

However, I find no possibility to use the federation login of the user pool over the API (not hosted UI).

A synonym to `Auth.signIn` but with federation facebook using react native, for example with expo.

With expo i get the facebook tokens via

```
const { type, token, expires } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(aws_exports.aws_facebook_id, {
  permissions: ['public_profile'],
});
```

How to use federated Auth using aws-amplify API without hosted UI?

Answer (score 4):

Amplify does not use a User Pool API for signing in via a third-party provider, and the APIs offered for third-party providers are just for Identity Pools. Currently, there's a feature request with the AWS Amplify SDK team for the same.

A workaround would be to use the [AUTHORIZATION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) Endpoint directly, and make suited HTTP requests to achieve your requirements.

Comment: can you link the mentioned feature request here, please. Thx

Answer (score -1):

Here's a post that shows how to use Google and Facebook to authenticate with the user pools.  It's way too much to repeat here, so check out the link.

https://dev.to/dabit3/the-complete-guide-to-user-authentication-with-the-amplify-framework-2inh

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Auth.Federated SignIn is for Identity Pools.

Comment: Per this link here - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#oauth-and-federation-overview

It appears that these methods will indeed create a user in the Cognito User Pool after completion of the flow.

Comment: @ArkaMukherjee `Auth.federatedSignIn` does work by redirecting the third-party approval through the hosted UI. There are other issues at play with getting it to work reliably (e.g. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7364), but calling that method directly does indeed lead to a User being created in a User Pool in addition to an identity pool.